# Questions about image output using C# OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv

I created a simple program that brings images to PictureBox when I click a button.
Please tell me why the exception occurs in the commented processed code.

**Code**

```
OpenCV_image = Cv2.ImRead(openFile_Dialog.FileName, ImreadModes.Grayscale);

// Line which raises exception
pictureBox1.Image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(OpenCV_image);
```

**Exception**

> System.AccessViolationException

I'm studying OpenCV for the first time, and I used Google to study and copy it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Mat OpenCV_image = Cv2.ImRead(openFileDialog1.FileName,   ImreadModes.Grayscale);
    Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(OpenCV_image.Cols, OpenCV_image.Rows, (int) OpenCV_image.Cols* 2, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, OpenCV_image.Data);
    pictureBox1.Image = newBmp;
```

ImRead() returns a Mat (matrix) and (although I haven't looked) I assume BitmapConverter  wants something else so you need to create a new bitmap and give it the data from the matrix along with the other info specified. You might need to fiddle with the stride values and pixel formats to get it all working correctly.